# How can I call a function in my main Activity class from a custom Gallery view in Android?

Tags: android

I have a custom gallery view in which I am overriding some methods.  I would like to be able to call a function in my main activity from this class.  How do I make a reference back to my main class?

I thought I'd just push the class reference into CustomGallery by creating a setter function --->  g.setBaseClass(this);

```
CustomGallery g = (CustomGallery) findViewById(R.id.playSelectionGallery);
g.setSpacing(10);
g.setCallbackDuringFling(false);
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
g.setSelection(1);
registerForContextMenu(g);
g.setBaseClass(this);
```

Problem is **this** is of type **Context** and **someFunctionToCall()** will result in a not a member of this class error.  In my custom class I have:

```
public void setBaseClass(Context baseClass)
{
    _baseClass = baseClass;
}
private void callSomeFuntionOnMyMainActivityClass()
{
    _baseClass.someFunctionToCall();
}
```

All I want to do is call back to my main class, called ViewFlipperDemo.  This would be easy in As3.  Any thoughts?  Hopefully I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's actually not a good idea... but you can do it this way:

```
private void callSomeFuntionOnMyMainActivityClass()
{
    ((ViewFlipperDemo)_baseClass).someFunctionToCall();
}
```

What you should do instead is implementing a simple observer which allows you to notify the Activity that something happened. That's one of the main OO principles, your custom class shouldn't know anything about your activity class.

#### Observer pattern example

The Observer interface:

```
// TheObserver.java
public interface TheObserver{
    void callback();
}
```

Your custom view:

```
public class CustomGallery{
    private TheObserver mObserver;

    // the rest of your class

    // this is to set the observer
    public void setObserver(TheObserver observer){
        mObserver = observer;
    }

    // here be the magic
    private void callSomeFuntionOnMyMainActivityClass(){
        if( mObserver != null ){
            mObserver.callback();
        }
    }
    // actually, callSomeFuntionOnMyMainActivityClass
    // is not a good name... but it will work for the example
 
}
```

This is the activity that will benefit of the observer (notice that now you can use your custom view on different activities not just one, that's one of the key reasons to implement it this way):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
    // your normal stuff bla blah

    public void someMethod(){
        CustomGallery g=(CustomGallery)findViewById(R.id.playSelectionGallery);
        g.setObserver(new TheObserver(){
            public void callback(){
                // here you call something inside your activity, for instance
                methodOnYourActivity();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will notice that this design pattern (observer) is widely used in Java and Android... almost any kind of UI event is implemented using observers (`OnClickListener`, `OnKeyListener`, etc.). By the way, I didn't test the code, but it should work.

Comment: I understand and agree.  I am so new to Android however that I am struggling to accomplish in proper form things I know how to do in As3.  Climbing up this learning curve, slowly lol.

Is there any significant reason I should avoid the above suggestion besides it being sloppy?  If so, what area should I study up on to understand how to implement your observer suggestion.  Looks like I'm going to have to start titling my posts "Dear Cristain" LOL..

Comment: OK, allow a couple of minutes... I will edit the question to give you a brief example.

Comment: awesome!  I really appreciate your help.  Seriously!  I have a couple of books on the way that will answer a lot of questions but until then you've been a fantastic help!  And I would never actually name a function that!!!  that was pseudo code.  \m/(>.<)\m/

Comment: i think this pattern is called "delegate" and not "observer"